# How do we do sajda tilawat if we recite Sura Inshiqaq (84) in the 1st rakah?

Tags: salat, hanafi, sajda, sajdat-al-tilaawah

Sura Inshiqaq (chapter 84) consists of 25 ayat. The 21st verse is Sajda ayah.

How is sajda tilawaat done if one recites the Sura Inshiqaq in the 1st rakah of his Salah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say takbeer and fall directly into prostration. After the single prostration you say takbeer and stand straight up; continue the recitation and then do ruku and  complete the first rakah. For demonstration refer to this [video](https://youtu.be/Y1HKj-mkdK0?t=291) (ignore the confused people at the back).

Comment: Except with the hanafi's all other sunni schools of fiqh say you must do takbeer before falling down into sujud and after finishing it, unlike the imam of al-Haram did in the video.

Comment: @UmH, Which Sura is he reciting? I couldn't identify. Which sajda ayah?

Comment: Surah As-Sajdah (32)