# Going direct into Sajood after qiyam

Tags: salat, practical-islam, sajdat-al-tilaawah

I was in fajr praying in a mosque today and in second Rakat the prayer leader said Takbir and everyone went direct into sujood. After takbir again everyone came back in qiyaam and continued the prayer normally, then ruku etc.

What confused me is why the prayer leader said Takbir long and everyone went to sujood? What is it called or is fajr suppose me like that?

Comment: Isn't that prostration of recitation ( sajdah Al tilawat)?. There are 15 such verses in the Quran to which we perform prostration out of humility. It's done in the prayer too when the imam recites such a verse, haven't heard of it?. What's the confusion then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that the qur'an includes so called verses of sujud or sujood, which a reciter who meets them and his audience is highly recommended to perform sujud if reading them. If the reciter performs sujud his audience basically must follow him if they have wudu'.

Further among the sunan of the day of Jumu'ah which is to recite surat as-Sajdah in the fajr prayer:

> The Apostle of Allah (ﷺ) used to recite in the morning prayer on Friday Surah" Alif-Lam-Mim, Tanz'il ul-Sajda" (Surah xxxii.): Surely there came over the man a time" (Surah lxxvii) and he used to recite in Jumu'a prayer Surahs Jumu'a and al-Munafiqin.
> (See in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:891) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:879a) and elsewhere)

In this context imam al-Qurafi quoted an anecdote that laymen thought that fajr or sobh on Friday is three raka'a because they saw their imam go down and standing up three times and counted the standing up after the sujud at-tilawah as another raka'.

So the imam apparently prayed and recited a verse including "sujud" like that of surat as-Sajda and after performing the sujud of recitation (sujud at-Tilawa) went back to a standing position and continued the recitation of the surah.

To be honest in some madhhabs it is recommended to avoid verses with sujud in congregational prayers, at least for the case of silent prayers like dhohr and 'asr this recommendation makes sense. But in jahri (in opposition to sirri ~ silent) prayers this recommendation would go against at least the sunnah of Friday.

For further information about verses were sujood is regarded as obligatory see for example:

[How many sajdas are in Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/how-many-sajdas-are-in-quran)
[Number of Prostrations in Quran in every Juz (1/30th part of Quran)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25529/number-of-prostrations-in-quran-in-every-juz-1-30th-part-of-quran)

Further on the how to:
[How do we do sajda tilawat if we recite Sura Inshiqaq (84) in the 1st rakah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63112/how-do-we-do-sajda-tilawat-if-we-recite-sura-inshiqaq-84-in-the-1st-rakah)

Comment: Thank you a great answer, Why are zuhr and asr prayer silent?